# Is a javascript code to remove blank lines fromt text in a textarea and copy to clipboard a server-side program

Tags: javascript

I have a tool I've created for work that removes blank lines from a confirmation and then copies to clip board.  I am wondering if these are server-side or client-side programs as the info pasted in the textarea is confidential.

```
<script> // logs "Copies to clipboard"
 function copyToClipboard(element) {
  var text = $(element).clone().find('br').prepend('\r\n').end().text()
  element = $('<textarea>').appendTo('body').val(text).select()
  document.execCommand('copy')
  element.remove()
   }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">// logs "Removes blank spaces"
    var viewModel = {
   myValue: ko.observable(''),
   cleared: ko.observable(false),
   clearValue: function() {       
   this.myValue('');   
   this.cleared(true);
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
```

Comment: All of that code executes on the client.

Comment: You use SSL to protect the information as it goes from the Client to the Server, and AES (or better) encryption on your database table columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of the script runs on the browser so its client side.